# Temperature Dependence of the Kubo Formula

Tags: condensed-matter, temperature, electrical-resistance, greens-functions, fermi-liquids

I'm trying to calculate the DC conductivity of a Renormalized Fermi Liquid with Green's function

\begin{equation}
G(i\omega,k)=\frac{Z}{i\omega-Z\tilde{\epsilon}_k-ig\omega^2}
\end{equation}

where $Z$ is the quasiparticle residue, $\tilde{\epsilon}_k$ is a renormalized band energy and $g\omega^2$ is the result of the self-energy (it's imaginary part to be precise). $g$ is just a coupling constant. There's a factor of $i$ in front of the frequency because I'm working with Matsubara frequencies.

The Kubo formula says that the conductivity can be calculated as

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{DC}=\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\ 0}\frac{1}{\omega}\text{Im}\big[\Pi(i\omega\rightarrow\omega+i\delta) \big] 
\end{equation}

where $\Pi$ is the current-current correlation and the evaluation on $\omega+i\delta$ get's as from the Matsubara correlator to the retarded propagator. Using the spectral density function

\begin{equation}
G(i\omega,k)=\int \frac{d\Omega}{2\pi}\frac{A(\Omega,k)}{i\omega-\Omega}
\end{equation}
we can reduce the conductivity to

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{DC}=\frac{N}{2}\int\frac{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d}\int\frac{d\Omega}{2\pi}A(\Omega,k)^2\ v(k)^2\ \big[-\frac{\partial n_F}{\partial \omega}(\Omega)\big]
\end{equation}

At this point every single paper and reference I find says that for $T<<E_F$ we can approximate

\begin{equation}
-\frac{\partial n_F}{\partial \omega}(\Omega)\approx\delta(\Omega)
\end{equation}

so we get

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{DC}=\frac{N}{2}\int{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d}A(0,k)^2\ v(k)^2\ 
\end{equation}

At this point I get confused about two things:

1. Since the self-energy of this particular system is a function of frequency alone, the spectral density function at $\Omega=0$ will be just a delta function. But the spectral density function is squared so it becomes divergent.
2. Even if we fix that by taking some smart limit, where is the temperature dependence of the conductivity? The delta appeared because we assumed $T<<E_F$ but that is far from meaning $T=0$. Is it related to the fact that the frequencies are actually Matsubara frequencies $\omega_n=\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{\beta}$ so the limit $\omega\rightarrow\ 0$ actually means $\omega\rightarrow\ \pi T$? I don't see where will the temperature appear otherwise.